# Vertically align inline object without height or width

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment

Given the following html:

```
<div class="body">    
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="name">
            <h2>
                <a href="http://www.example.com">
                    <span class="bold">Test Link</span><br/>
                </a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <h3>A Connections Learning Partner Program</h3>
            <p>Quality online learning for high school students in Oakland County and surrounding counties.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <a href="http://www.example.com">Learn More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I vertically align `.link a` (the button) within `.link` without giving a height or width? Like this...

[image]

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/9sUMz/)

Comment: I updated the answer to allow more flexibility and control over the various elements.  Please review. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc Audet was very close but I ended up going a slightly different route.

I gave `.link a` a fixed top margin and made `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` and that did the trick.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bflemi3/9sUMz/6/) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way that you can do it.  Your HTML is good, no need to change anything.

For the CSS:

```
.body { width: 920px; }

.banner {
    background-color: #454545;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F9F9F9;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
}

.banner > div {
    outline: 1px dotted yellow; /* optional to show cell edges... */
    display: table-cell;
}

.banner .name {
    width: 25%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 25px; /* control top white space */
    text-align: center;
}

.banner .name h2 {
    color: #F9F9F9;
    max-height: 55px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.banner .title {
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.banner .title h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.banner .title p {
    font-size: 12px;
    max-height: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.banner .link {
    width: 25%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left; /* set to left, center or right as needed */
}

.banner .link a {
    margin-left: 25px; /* controls left offset */
    background-color: #FA9800;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block; /* use inline-block if you want to center element */
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 23px;
    line-height: 23px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100px;
}
```

See the fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/jsG8F/

**How This Works**

The trick is to use `display: table` on your `.banner` container and then `display: table-cell` on your child `div` elements, and set the % widths to 25%, 50%, 25% respectively for `.name`, `.title`, `.link`.

You can then use `vertical-align` and `text-align` to control vertical and horizontal placement of the various text blocks.

I added comments related to using `padding-top` to control white space from the top of the banner.

For the `.link a` element, you can adjust the left margin (or right) as needed.

These CSS rules offer you a lot of fine control over the placement of the various elements within the banner.

**Backwards Compatibility**

The `display: table-cell` property is backwards compatible back to IE8.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: sorry, how would you go about centering horizontally as well?

Comment: `display: table-cell` will not work with older IE browsers.  In such cases, you loose the vertical centering.  As for horizontal centering, what is the space where the link will be centered?

Comment: Since `div.title` is a fixed width, I would like it to be horizontally centered between that and the end of the parent div `div.banner`. The picture above somewhat shows what it should look like, although it's not perfectly centered between the two points I mentioned above.

Comment: Do you want `.name` and `.title` to be vertically centered like `.link`?

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the element and banner are fixed, use `margin-top` to offset the element.